# Translation of 'f agit sur C'

Tags: mathematical-french

In a French mathematical paper I am reading, there is the following situation: let $f,\sigma:A\rightarrow A$ two group homomorphisms and there is an $N$ such that $\ker (f)\subseteq C = \ker(\sigma^N -1)$. What does this mean in English: if we choose $N$ sufficiently large then we may assume that 'f agit sur C'?

Comment: "(the function) $f$ acts on $C$"

Comment: ...the verb being "agir"

Comment: So the group $A$ is abelian?

Comment: Yes, it is an abelian variety, could that be relevant to the translation?

Comment: Maybe not, but it is certainly relevant in order to speak of $\ker(\sigma^N-1)$

Answer (score 0):

"$f$ agit sur $C$" simply means the function $f$ maps the elements of $C$.

Depending on the context, this could sometimes mean that $C$ is then the domain of $f$.

However, as Jean-Marie pointed out, in this case, it probably doesn't mean that. 
 We need more details to know this.

Comment: I am sorry but I think it's more than that: it is the action of a group on a set... but we have not enough elements to be sure of that.

Comment: You're right, I generalised the idea too much.  Corrected.